# При обработки текста регексом, выдирается лишний символ!

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, .net

При обработке текстовой строки вида:

```
drwxrwxrwx    5 1002     1003         4096 Feb 11 15:05 HTML
```

регулярный выражением вида:

```
(?<dir>[\-d])(?<permissions>([\-r][\-w][\-xs]){3})\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(?<size>\d+)\s+(?<timestamp>\w+\s+\d+\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s+(?<name>.+)\s*
```

в группу `<name>` кроме самого "HTML", выдирается еще то ли пробел, то ли символ переноса строки. Точно не могу сказать, но в TextBox'e (WinForms) этот символ отображается квадратиком.
Как сделать, что бы "HTML" выдиралось в `<name>` без этого символа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил сам!
Вместо (?<name>.+)s* сделал (?<name>[^s]+)!